# Label scatter points in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 3 columns, "Price" (decimal), "Returns" (decimal), and "Ticker" (text). I would like to create a scatter plot in PowerBI. In the scatter plot, I would like each point to be labelled with text from the Ticker column, within the plot area.

All the columns are set to `Don't summarize`.

My research led me to believe that I'm supposed to have a "Details" option, but I don't that option.

I dragged "Returns" (numerical column) to the x Axis, and "Price" (another numerical column) to the Y axis. I then turned on the category labels option, but the chart shows "Returns" and "Price" labels, instead of showing me "Ticker" (the text column) labels.

[image: Sample data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the setting of the parameter fields

[image]

Then go to the formatting pane and select Category label **On**

[image]